# Is there a way to click button with name ignorecase

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I am trying to click on a button in which text="Settings" or text="SETTINGS" using ignorecase.

My code:-

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, THIRTY_SECONDS);

    return wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.name("Settings")));
```

How Can i click button with ignore case ? Is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following xpath by using the `translate()` function and `contains()` function:

```
String xpath = "//*[contains(translate(text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 'settings')]"
```

This will select elements containing text "settings" or "Settings" or "SETTINGS". Your code will then be:

```
return wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpath)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to get a list of all elements in the current activity, and use string moethods to check the Text attribute. just make sure that you use try - cat when you are check the Text field to avoid Exceptions.